# How to read raw serial data using Java?

Tags: java, serial-port, serial-communication, parity

I am currently implementing Slot accounting system to interface with Slot machines using [SAS602](https://support.igt.com/apps/sas-protocol.aspx). This protocol uses non Standard 9-bit protocol for Serial communication.  So the data is 
1 start bit + 8 data bit+ 1 stop bit + 1 wake up bit( parity bit in my case)

The slot machine identifies the address byte and data byte based on wake up bit. If it is set then the byte is address and cleared then it is data byte.

It is also mentioned in the protocol where 9 bit support is not available it recommended to use Mark/space parity. I am on Java with [jserialcom](http://fazecast.github.io/jSerialComm/)  and managed to established connection with the slot machine and read data. However I am unable to differentiate between data and address byte because with jserialcomm library readbytes strips the raw data and provides me only the data byte. 
I have no access to parity bit state.

Is it possible to get the raw 11-bit data with Java? Is it even possible? If so how do I go about doing it?

I am open any library or Linux platform.

Comment: Well, if that one library doesn't give you what you need; I would start looking for alternatives. Worst case, you would have to look into source code; and come up with your own version of that thing ... adapting it to you needs.

Comment: I'll bet you will have to resort to raw sockets and dealing with all that messiness on your own.  If the Slot vendor doesn't provide such a library, I doubt that anyone else will.  Voting to close - not a fit for SO.

Comment: *"So the data is 1 start bit + 8 data bit+ 1 stop bit + 1 wake up bit"* -- It's illogical to have an information bit outside the frame (i.e. after the stop bit).  *"Is it possible to get the raw 11-bit data with ...?"* -- No UART/USART/SSC preserves the start & stop framing bits.  They contain no information since they are fixed values.

Comment: @sawdust  In 9-bit UART the 9th bit is stored in a separate register it's not part of the Data. Since I am using Parity bit as the wake up bit. I have added it at the end.  How about the parity bit? Is it possible to know the parity bit for every byte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended by modifying the Jserialcomm library to ignore parity checking when receiving data and set the parity bits when transmitting data. The error checking on received  data is based solely on CRC. This works fine so far.

Although the above could be achieved by setting NO_PARITY on received data. MARK and SPACE Parity when sending bytes. When switching  parity with Jserialcomm library because there is a delay of 200ms when setting parity. This again results in loss of data. I am not entirely sure why there should be such a delay.

There is also option in the Linux to add 255 0 to every single byte received whenever there is an error after parity checking. This could be applied reversing the parity checking mechanism. But this method is also prone to error because adding extra bytes takes time and you might end up loosing a lot of data. This also requires modification to Jserialcomm library.

Answer (score 2):

Because the 9th bit is not data but carry control information, you can enable parity checking when configuring serial port. Now when data is received count number of 1's in received byte and check if parity error has occurred or not. If it has not occurred and you know number of 1's you can easily deduce that the parity bit is 1 or 0 and hence data or control.

Also take a look at [this article](https://github.com/RishiGupta12/SerialPundit/blob/master/applications/9-bit-data.md) about 9th bit in serial port.